# Incrementing time in excel macro

Tags: excel, time, increment, vba

I need an excel macro to increment a time by a half hour. I will also use the code to modify other cells but I cant get this first part working. The cell lets sat A1 is in Time format ie 12:00:00 PM.
Am new to this so am sure the answer is simple.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What code do you have so far? Do you want a formula or VBA module?

Comment: I am looking for a VBA module

Comment: Private Sub Adjust_Pk_()
Dim PkTime
PkTime = Range("B53").Value
Range("B53").Value = PV + Time(0.5, 0, 0)
End Sub

Answer (score 0):

To bump A1 by 30 minutes:

```
Sub Bump30Minutes()
    With Range("A1")
        .Value = .Value + TimeSerial(0, 30, 0)
    End With
End Sub
```